# microphone trouble

Tags: microphone, diagnostic

I am trying to use my Google Voice and the other party cannot hear me.  So I tried recoding something and it did not work. So how do I run some sort of diagnostic to check to see of my microphone is working?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Sound Menu indicator, up right of your screen. Select "Sound Settings…".
In the newly opened app, go to the "Input" tab. If a sound input device is detected, it should then appear in the list on the left and you can make some tests on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Sound system Icon (looks like a speaker) go to "Sound Settings".

In sound settings there is an "Input" tab click on it.

On the left hand side you should see all the detected input devices on the right you will see the available options for the selected device. If the device is muted (default behavior) you will need to un-mute it before the Input Level monitor will display the detected sound.

If it still isn't detecting sound or if your device isn't showing up we will need more information about the device in question to help further.